# Is that a need to add every investors to multisig wallet?

Tags: multisignature, ico, crowdsale

I read an [article here](https://cointelegraph.com/explained/how-to-launch-a-successful-ico-explained), it mentioned that

> Another convention which has by now become a de facto requirement is collecting all contribution in a multi-signature escrow wallet, with all the names of all key holders announced to the public.

During crowdsale, we provide the contract address in our website, and investors will send ETH to that contract, the ETH will then stored in a multisig wallet, and investors receive the token accordingly.

Is it the usual way to add the investors as the one of the owner of that multisig wallet?

Please advice. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The investors are not owners of the multisig, the founders of the project are.

The standard is for the token contract to implement [ERC20](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard) such that investors can transfer their tokens (etc).

Multisignature features are used such that owners can not withdraw the proceeds of the crowdsale without multiple signatures.

It gives investors confidence, and protects the owners.

Comment: oh... so the investors need not to add to the wallet, as long as the wallet need multiple signature from multiple owners will do?

Comment: Your comment is not clear.

Comment: i mean, is the investors gain confidence, if the wallet have multiple owners?

Comment: Yes. Because they know that one rogue owner can't steal their funds.